# Haskell use main load a file , how to write address

Tags: haskell

Here I have text file, I want to load it in Haskell, and read it in a List.

```
import qualified System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [path] <- System.Environment.getArgs
    g <- readFile path
    putStr g
```

But I don't know how to give the address. (Example: the file is `/Users/Documents/Programming/test.txt`)

After I load this Haskell file:

```
*Main> main -- How can I write the address?
```

Comment: Try compiling and running it instead of loading it into ghci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `:help`, you can see documentation for the `:main` command:

> ```
>   :main [<arguments> ...]     run the main function with the given arguments
> ```

Example:

```
ghci> :main /Users/Documents/Programming/test.txt
...
contents of test.txt
...
```

Comment: Thanks  for your help. I tried this way , but <interactive>:2:175:
    Not in scope: ‘main’
    Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)